# how to map implicit class parameter to trait variable?

Tags: scala, inheritance, implicit, traits

I face interesting problem with implicit parameters and tratis.

I have an abstract class `Parent` accepting one integer and 2 other params implicitely:

```
abstract class Parent(a: Int)(implicit str: String, map: Map[String,String]) {/*...*/}
```

and a trait `ClassTrait` that will be mixed with `Parent` and uses the implicits:

```
trait ClassTrait {
    val str: String
    val map: Map[String,String]

    def doSth() = str.length
}
```

so now I want to make sth like this (**withnout** keyword `abstract`):

```
class Child(a: Int)(implicit str: String, map: Map[String,String]) extends Parent(a) with ClassTrait {
    def doSth2 = doSth * 10
}
```

What syntax should I use to **map the implicit params to trait vals**? Compiler returns this error:

```
foo.scala:10: error: class Child needs to be abstract, since:
value map in trait ClassTrait of type Map[String,String] is not defined
value str in trait ClassTrait of type String is not defined
class Child(a: Int)(implicit str: String, map: Map[String,String]) extends Parent(a) with ClassTrait {
      ^
one error found
```

In complex example, I use implicit parameters in the trait but since traits can't have any params (have no constructor), I need to declare used implicits again.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
class Child(a: Int)(implicit val str: String, map: Map[String,String]) extends Parent(a) with ClassTrait {
   def doSth2 = doSth * 10
 }
```

(See the `val` I added)

Or use `case class`. Then they will be fields.

Alternative way could be to not make them implicit and use an apply method in a companion object that takes implicits to set them. But you still need to make them fields, your current code is technically just treating them as constructor args.

Answer (score 2):

You could promote your class parameters to fields, using the val keyword:

```
abstract class Parent(a: Int)(implicit val str: String, val map: Map[String,String]) {/*...*/}
```

Note the "val str" and "val map" instead of just "str" and "map". This way they will be proper read-only members and provide implementations for the abstract members of your trait.

Comment: I answered 3 seconds sooner than you apparently!! Haha :)